# How can I tell at what time a YouTube video went online?

Tags: youtube

Looking at a YouTube video, I can only tell which *date* it went online. Is it possible to also see at what *time* (in hours and perhaps minutes) it was published?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get it using just YouTube, YouTube doesn't allow it.

You can get using a tool called [YouTube Data Viewer](http://www.amnestyusa.org/citizenevidence/).

1. Paste the URL in the input.
2. Click Go button.
3. You can convert the time in your time zone.

[image: example output]